Stop Chrome iOS auto-detecting numbers followed by letter "m" as metre units, and adding an underline to auto-convert the unit to other lengths
Chrome for iOS is detecting a number immediately followed by the letter “m” as a metres length unit, and it adds a dotted underline to it which when tapped offers a unit conversion feature.
Ideally I would like to disable this feature for certain parts of text. If that is not possible, disabling it for the whole document would be an OK compromise. A HTML or CSS solution is requested.
The solution must be A11y friendly (so no replacement characters) and not use JS. I am unable to edit the text, or change the “m“ at the end of the number, so no suggestions that require a change in markup of the text itself. A change in markup to tags around the text would be acceptable.
See images attached for further details of the UI of the feature, you'll notice the auto-generated dotted underlines on numbers followed by a letter "m". Tapping any of those numbers results in seeing the unit conversion feature appear.
 
I can’t find any documentation about this feature, I can’t even find the feature name. Searching Chrome's dev blog yielded no useful results for me either, so if anyone can provide links to any articles about this feature or official documentation for it, that would be very appreciated too.
Here's the raw HTML:
<div class="cell-text">
  <h5>5m tpy</h5>
  <p>Direct reduced iron production capacity</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>8,000+</h5>
  <p>Steel Professionals</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>$5.9bn</h5>
  <p>Total investments</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>450+</h5>
  <p>Steel grades</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>$100m</h5>
  <p>Invested in CSR projects</p>
</div>



UPDATE: I've added an image below of the UI displayed when tapping the "Report an issue" link at the bottom of the feature. It shows a feedback submission page which references Google, not Apple, which makes me think this is a Chrome feature, not an iOS one.


UPDATE 6/9/24: I’m no longer experiencing this auto-detection feature for the same page in iOS Chrome 128.0.6613.98 so I’m assuming it was a bug in a previous release.

Are we sure this is a browser feature and not an extension or an IOS feature?

I can’t reproduce this on Chrome IOS 16.7.8 What device and version of IOS are you on.

@Paulie_D its not an extension, i don't have any installed. If it was an iOS feature i'd expect it to be present in Safari too, but it's not. Only Chrome.

@AHaworth iOS 17.5.1 , Chrome version 126.0.6478.54

Hmm, this indicates it's a hidden feature since IOS 16 - not sure how you disable it - https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/ios-16-has-hidden-unit-converter-for-temperatures-time-zones-distance-and-other-measurements-0385095/ Somewhere in "Settings" perhaps?

@Paulie_D whats interesting is when i create a reduced test case on Codepen, with the same markup as above, it doesn't auto-detect the unit values and offer them up for conversion with a dotted underline: https://codepen.io/tfoh/full/abgzzvW so the auto-detect behaviour does not appear to be consistent from initial findings.

@Paulie_D when i tap the "Report an issue" link at the bottom of the feature, I get shown a feedback submission page which references Google, not Apple, which makes me think this is a Chrome feature, not an iOS one. I've updated my question with a screenshot of that for reference.

If anyone can find the settings for iOS's inbuilt unit conversion feature as pointed out in the article posted by @Paulie_D, then i can test switching it off and seeing if the unit auto-detection is still occurring within Chrome iOS.

You can disable it in settings/Contents settings/Detect Units.
The web site can also disable it using the meta
<meta name="chrome" content="nointentdetection">


Thanks for that. Do you happen to know where this meta tag name and content attribute are documented?

I had a look on https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/special-tags and can't see any info related to the chrome name attribute value or the nointentdetection content attribute value

I just spent several days banging my head on the computer over this new "feature". It appears to be, in some fashion, causing a removeNode error upon re-renders in MUI (react). I had a <Typography> component with child text containing the words "25 miles" that kept crapping out my application if the component re-rendered. I solved by replacing the child of my <Typography> component with a template literal.

Thats interesting, thanks for commenting. Hopefully we can build out some further understanding of this feature and it's implications within this thread

The issue is that there is a "Detect Units" feature in Google Chrome, but it no longer exists. It is speculated that Google has remotely turned it off

Thanks for contributing. If you know where to find them, could you share any links relating to the "Detect Units" feature you mentioned, and also where it was speculated that it has been remotely turned off.

I’m no longer experiencing this auto-detection feature for the same page in iOS Chrome 128.0.6613.98 so I’m assuming it was a bug in a previous release. Closed.
